# Function $f(\sin(x)) + f(\cos(x))$

Tags: functions, trigonometry, functional-equations, substitution

Consider a real valued function $f$ such that
$f(\sin(x)) + f(\cos(x)) = 2x - \frac{\pi}{2}$
Is there a way to find the range of $f(x)$?

I tried substituting $x$ as $\frac{\pi}{2}-x$, but that gives $x = \frac{\pi}{4}$ - which is a single value as opposed to a function. Is there a way to find out what the function is and its range?

Comment: You have shown that there does not exist a function $f$ satisfying that equation for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: It is impossible for this equation to be true for all real $x$, because the left side is periodic with period $2\pi$ but the right side is not.

Comment: it is a pity that you used the variable $x$ when asking for the range, because it makes it difficult to talk about the interval of $x$ values for which the equation is valid without confusing these values with the domain of $f$. To me, it would have been clearer to have just asked for the range of $f$

Comment: no function exists that can satisfy the equation for any interval containing both $x=0$ and $x= \frac \pi 2$

Comment: no differentiable function exists that can satisfy the equation for any interval containing $x = \frac \pi 4$

Comment: @WW1 Then how to find range of $f$ In answer key $f(x)=\dfrac {4}{3} \sqrt{(1-x^2)}-\dfrac{\pi}{12}\; $ is given. How did they obtain $f(x)$