Find $f(x)$ assuming that $f(\sin x)+f(\cos x)=2x-\frac{\pi}{2}$

If $f(x)$ is a real valued function such that $$f(\sin x)+f(\cos x)=2x-\frac{\pi}{2}$$
Find $f(x)$.

I did $x\to\arcsin x$ and then $x\to \arccos x$ and I obtained $2\arcsin x=2\arccos x$ or $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$
But I guess whatever I have found is absurd.
How to approach this question$?$ Any help is greatly appreciated.

There is no such function. Changing $x$ to $\frac {\pi} 2-x$ gives a contradiction.

The left-hand side is a periodic function, and the right-hand side it not periodic. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4086948/42969.

@MartinR in the answer key they have given $f(x)=\frac{4}{3} \sqrt{1-x^2}-\frac{\pi}{12}$....this is incorrect, right?? And I have to find the range of $f(x)$ in the original question

@geetha290krm means whatever I found wasn't absurd??

Have a look at the comments to the question from the above link.

Important information is missing: Do you require that the identitiy holds for all $x \in \Bbb R$? Or are you looking for functions such that the identity holds for all $x$ in some interval or some other domain? The answer depends on that.

@MartinR most probably for all x belongs to R


Claim: There exists no function $f$ that satisfies $f(\sin x)+f(\cos x)=2x-\frac{\pi}{2}$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$

We prove the above claim by contradiction.
If the claim is true, then $f(\sin a)+f(\cos a)=2a-\frac{\pi}{2}$ for some $a \in \mathbb R$. Then since $\cos x = \sin (\pi /2 - x)$ and $\sin x = \cos (\pi /2 - x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$, we substitute to find that:
$$2a-\frac{\pi}{2} = 2( \pi / 2 - a)-\frac{\pi}{2} \iff a = \pi / 4$$
Therefore, this only holds if the $a$ we chose earlier was $\pi / 4$. However, this contradicts our assumption that the expression holds true more generally, since $a$ was chosen arbitrarily from $\mathbb R$.
This shows that there is no such function $f$ that allows the expression in the question to hold true for all $x \in \mathbb R$.

For $x=0$ (meaning that $\sin(x) = 0$ and $\cos(x) = 1$), we can easily see that:
$$f(0) + f(1) = - \frac{\pi}{2}$$
For $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ (meaning that $\sin(x) = 1$ and $\cos(x) = 0$), we can easily see that:
$$f(1) + f(0) = \pi - \frac{\pi}{2} = \frac{\pi}{2}$$
In other words, your function can't exist!

Although there are enough awswers, let me add one.
For LHS, we can deduce that $2\pi$-periodic. (Since
$$f(\sin(x+2\pi))+f(\cos(x+2\pi))=f(\sin x)+f(\cos x)$$
) but RHS isn't. So there is no such $f$.
If the given equation has unknown function and known functions, you can use symmetry, periodicity, asymptotes, etcs for deduce that "unknown function" does not exist.
